# 2015 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/655/2015-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire).**

Here's how it'll work:

- During the nomination phase, (so, until Monday, December 14th at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 3:00 pm EST on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The first two will be guaranteed to be included, the latter ones are if the community doesn't supply enough questions. This will be done in a single post, unlike the prior instruction.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into at current.
- At the end of the phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election. That said, if I have concerns about any questions in this fashion, I will be sure to point this out in comments before the decision making time.
- Once questions have been selected, a new question will be opened to host the actual questionnaire for the candidates, containing 10 questions in total.
- This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Answer (score 6):

What do you think are the biggest issues Raspberry Pi SE could face in the future - and how as a moderator would you go about solving them?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a set of general questions, gathered as very common questions asked every election. As mentioned in the instructions, the first two questions are guaranteed to show up in the Q&A, while the others are if there aren't enough questions (or, if you like one enough, you may split it off as a separate answer for review within the community's 8).

- How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
- How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

---

- In your opinion, what do moderators do?
- A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
- In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Answer (score 5):

The products made by the Raspberry Pi foundation are aimed at all ages and skill levels, including children and beginners with technology. As such, many of those who use this site for the first time may not be familiar with the ethics of our site (and the internet in general).

In the past this has brought many low quality questions and answers with problems such as:

- Non attempt or incorrect use of spelling, punctuation and grammar
- Insufficient formatting (code blocks not formatted etc)
- Incorrect tagging (such as using [raspberry-pi-foundation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raspberry-pi-foundation) on every question)
- Lack of details which were essential to answer the question (asking why their GPIO setup won't work, but without submitting code and circuit diagrams)
- Against site guidelines (e.g. expecting users to watch a youtube video for essential details, off-topic questions, broad questions, etc)

We have a huge backlog of these questions and answers, and while some of these have been fixed, most of them have not.

**As a moderator, what can you do to help clean up this site, and keep it clean in the future?**

Comment: On a side note, I'm thinking of starting a clean up effort soon, so stay tuned!

Comment: @SlySven thanks, just a typo

Comment: Don't correct "incorrect use of spelling, punctuation and grammar". Many such attempts on this site contain errors themselves. Editing a post misrepresents the poster who has a right to his own words. If you think you can understand it so can the rest of us.

Comment: @Milliways Since when was editing to correct punctuation etc against the rules or discouraged? On nearly every site of the network (excluding ELL.SE and other language learning sites) editing to correct spelling and grammar is the right thing to do and is explicitly encouraged. If you think this type of editing is against the user's freedom of speech, I really suggest you read [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7918/about-the-violence-inherent-in-stack-exchange-freedom-of-speech) post on Arqade meta which explains this very well.

Comment: I never said it was "against the rules". I was expressing an opinion. I find it annoying when someone "corrects" my grammar. My expression may be idiosyncratic, but it is mine. I always revert any such attempt.

Comment: @Milliways - if the poster of something wants to edit it them-self to correct a spelling mistake - why is that a problem?  As it happens I alerted the OP to an error, **they** fixed it, and graciously (IMHO) thanked me.  Since my comment was no longer relevant I deleted it to reduce the SNR and everyone should be happy.

Comment: {As the poster explicitly referred to a problem of (uncorrected) spelling errors amongst other things - it would have been ironically unfortunate to accidentally leave one in their posting. 8-P }

Comment: @SlySven I was not objecting to users editing their own posts, or requesting others to do so. I routinely edit my own. I was objecting to the proposal that "Non(sic) attempt or incorrect use of spelling ⋯" makes a post "low quality".
These may look the poster look ill-educated, but still represent a reasonable post. After all many users of this Forum are not native English speakers (including most of the inhabitants of North America ;-) ). I have my own foibles; if you start a Question with "So" I am less likely to read on and I wince at "off of". Spelling and grammar vary between cultures.

Answer (score 2):

As a Moderator it is conceivable that the users of your Stack Exchange Community will ask you about a desirable feature for your Community that the parent SE organisation:

does not currently provide;

can never provide;

how would you work out the difference and what would you aim to do for each?